# Website Mirroring StackExchange

Tags: support, scraper-sites

The website `http://www.rqgg.net/index.html` seems to be stealing information from several StackExchange sites, including Mathematics. What is the appropriate way to report this, if it has not been done already?

Comment: See also: [Website plagiarizing math.stackexchange material](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/website-plagiarizing-math-stackexchange-material)

Comment: Maybe also this one : http://qaoverflow.com/question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This meta.SO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131846/report-sites-that-use-se-content-without-following-attribution-rules-here) is for reporting such sites. I went through the current answers and the one you found doesn't seem to be there, so report away!

[See also this meta.SO thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24611).

Comment: Reported. Thank you.